# All of a sudden migrate command in laravel 8 does not work

Tags: mysql, laravel-8

When I created a new Model (Category) with its migration and made changes by adding fields to the new structure of the categories. I also modified the existing posts table structure by adding fields to it  and then I went to migrate, (`php artisan migrate`) an error like:

**Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1813 Tablespace for table '`laravel_cms`.`migrations`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT (SQL: create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int
not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')**
occurred

I also executed

```
**php artisan migrate:install
php artisan migrate
php artisan migrate:reset
composer dump-autoload**
```

and other commands

but to no avail

When I went to the phpMyAdmin and clicked on migration table I got the following error and it was empty of data:

```
#1932 - Table 'laravel_cms.migrations' doesn't exist in engine
```

I also got the same error when I clicked on other tables. Also the posts table disappeared and the categories table not existing but its model was created. All migrations are available. I would appreciate any assistance. Any googled attempt to solve the issue has already failed.

Comment: If you update your laravel version- in composer.json change version of laravel framework and run command php artisan migrate, its work fine, whenever you update laravel